# CMake FIND_LIBRARY: link to specified library error

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I have already installed the FFTW3 library on my computer and the following files could be found in /usr/lib:

```
libfftw3f.so.3          libfftw3l_threads.so.3
libfftw3f.so.3.3.0      libfftw3l_threads.so.3.3.0
libfftw3f_threads.so.3      libfftw3.so.3
libfftw3f_threads.so.3.3.0  libfftw3.so.3.3.0
libfftw3l.so.3          libfftw3_threads.so.3
libfftw3l.so.3.3.0      libfftw3_threads.so.3.3.0
```

I want to install another package that needs to link these libraries, but when I try 
`FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES fftw3)` and `FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES fftw3f)`, 
it just cannot find the libraries.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Code in CMakeLists.txt:

```
FIND_PATH(FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR fftw3.h)
IF(FFLD_HOGPYRAMID_DOUBLE)
  FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES libfftw3.so.3)
ELSE()
  FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES libfftw3f.so.3)
ENDIF()
#IF(NOT FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR OR NOT FFTW3_LIBRARIES)
IF(NOT FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR OR NOT FFTW3_LIBRARIES)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find fftw3.")
ENDIF()
```

error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find fftw3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **gui-cmake**, http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html.

Then you can select the library needed manually.

Answer (score 3):

You have the dynamic libraries installed, but do you have the "development" package installed?  You probably need a file or symlink named something like:

```
libfftw3.so
```

You might need to install an fftw3-devel (or fftw3-dev) package.

Also, try removing the "lib" prefix and the .so.3 suffix:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES NAMES fftw3 libfftw3)
```

If that doesn't work, try adding the PATHS argument:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(FFTW3_LIBRARIES NAMES fftw3 libfftw3 PATHS /usr/lib <other paths>)
```

Make sure the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH variable is set correctly (presumably you're not cross-compiling, so it's likely empty, and cmake will be using sensible locations for finding libraries).

See the cmake man page for detailed usage of the find_library function.

Lastly, look at this site for how to write a find_package script:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

Comment: That link in the last line of your answer was helpful -- thanks! (I've gotten to it too many times, but breezed over looking for an easy answer. Finally I decided to really read through it, and I wasn't disappointed.)

Answer (score 1):

I would normally expect to see symlinks like `/usr/lib/libfftw.so -> libfftw.so.3`.  If those were in place, your `find_library` calls should work OK.

If you don't want to add symlinks, you can change your calls to:

```
find_library(FFTW3_LIBRARIES libfftw3.so.3 /usr/lib)
find_library(FFTW3F_LIBRARIES libfftw3f.so.3 /usr/lib)
```

Comment: Yes these libraries are in /usr/lib/ but find_library(FFTW3_LIBRARIES libfftw3.so.3)
find_library(FFTW3F_LIBRARIES libfftw3f.so.3) does not work :(

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the error message you're getting please?

Comment: Going by your code, that message could mean that the includes path is not found.  Can you print the values of `${FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR}` *and* `${FFTW3_LIBRARIES}` please?

Comment: I've checked FFTW3_INCLUDE_DIR and it's found and the only problem is FFTW3_LIBRARIES...It could not be found so I can not print the value...

Comment: I updated the answer to include `/usr/lib` as the path argument of `find_library`.  Can you give that a go?

Comment: It still does not work... I solved this problem by loading the library directly using GUI-Cmake. But I would still want to know how could I make this work. Thanks.