# Finding a directory in CMake

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake

### The problem:

I want to add the [boost numeric bindings](http://mathema.tician.de/software/boost-numeric-bindings) as an include directory in my build. This is typically compiled as:

`c++ -I/where/you/want/to/install/it/include/boost-numeric-bindings`

All of the header files I reference from my program are all relative to this directory, so in CMake I want to find this directory (wherever it is installed on the parent system) and add it to the `include_directories`.

### What I'm looking for:

Something like this:

```
find_directory(BNB_INCLUDE_DIR boost-numeric-bindings)

include_directories(${BNB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But the `find_directory` command does not exist. Am I missing something here?

### What I've tried:

I've tried:

```
find_path(BNB_INCLUDE_DIR boost/numeric/bindings/traits/ublas_vector.hpp)

include_directories(${BNB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

(which is the first file I need from the library) but this gives me the full path to the file and not the path to the directory containing the entire prefix to the file specified in the command.

Answer (score 6):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642703/189878) for information on how to write a cmake Find file.  As an example, here is one that I wrote for the lm-sensors library:

```
# - Try to find the LM_SENSORS library.
#
# The following are set after configuration is done: 
#  LM_SENSORS_FOUND
#  LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIRS
#  LM_SENSORS_LIBRARY_DIRS
#  LM_SENSORS_LIBRARIES

find_path(LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES sensors/sensors.h)
find_library(LM_SENSORS_LIBRARY NAMES libsensors sensors)

message("LM_SENSORS include dir = ${LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("LM_SENSORS lib = ${LM_SENSORS_LIBRARY}")

set(LM_SENSORS_LIBRARIES ${LM_SENSORS_LIBRARY})
set(LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIR})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
# Handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set the LM_SENSORS_FOUND to TRUE
# if all listed variables are TRUE
find_package_handle_standard_args(LM_SENSORS DEFAULT_MSG
                                  LM_SENSORS_LIBRARY LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(LM_SENSORS_INCLUDE_DIR LM_SENSORS_LIBRARY)
```

Change the above to match your library (`boost-numeric-bindings`), name the file `Findboost-numeric-bindings.cmake`, and put it in your cmake module dir (or create one of these in your source tree).

Then in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, do this:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} your_cmake_module_dir)
find_package (boost-numeric-bindings REQUIRED)
include_directories(${BOOST_NUMERIC_BINDINGS_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Then, assuming you don't have the library installed in a standard location, run cmake as follows:

`cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING="/where/you/have/installed/it/" <source path>`

**Edit**

Make sure you have defined a project before you call `find_path` or `find_package`.  Otherwise `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH` will not be set.  For example:

```
find_path (BOOST_STATE_HPP boost/statechart/state.hpp)
message ("CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
message ("CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH}")
message ("CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH}")
message ("CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
message ("BOOST_STATE_HPP=${BOOST_STATE_HPP}")

project (my_project)
```

will result in the following cmake output:

```
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=
CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH=
CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH=
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=
BOOST_STATE_HPP=BOOST_STATE_HPP-NOTFOUND
```

whereas this:

```
project (my_project)

find_path (BOOST_STATE_HPP boost/statechart/state.hpp)
message ("CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
message ("CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH}")
message ("CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH}")
message ("CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
message ("BOOST_STATE_HPP=${BOOST_STATE_HPP}")
```

results in sucessfully finding `state.hpp` and setting `BOOST_STATE_HPP` to `/usr/include`, as you desire:

```
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=
CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/w32api;/usr/X11R6/include;/usr/include/X11;/usr/pkg/include;/opt/csw/include;/opt/include;/usr/openwin/include
CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH=
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=
BOOST_STATE_HPP=/usr/include
```

Comment: I can imagine using something like this for a non-standard install, but typically (at least on unix) the bindings are installed to `/usr/local/include/boost-numeric-bindings`. I want this to be found automatically by CMake if it is here (or in the Windows equivalent).

Comment: If it is installed in a standard location, cmake already looks there when you use `find`.  Then you just don't need to specify `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when you run cmake.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was confusing...The standard install location for this package is `/usr/local/include/boost-numeric-bindings`, which is not a standard include path (e.g., `/usr/local/include`), so the build system doesn't know where to find the header files without explicitly including the `boost-numeric-bindings` directory. I want a way for CMake to look through the standard locations for the directory `boost-numeric-bindings` and return the full path of that directory.

Comment: How is what you added in your edit any different from what I already tried to do? The path will be set as `/usr/local/include/boost-numeric-bindings/boost/numeric/bindings/traits/`, when all I want is `/usr/local/include/boost-numeric-bindings/`. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work that way for me (cmake 2.8.10.2).  If the file is found using any of the search paths (see `find_path` description in `man cmake`) as a prefix, it will set the prefix in your variable's value.

Comment: Hmm, `/usr/include` is not listed in `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH`, so it must be getting that from another cmake variable.  Can't seem to find which one that is, though.